# Need a shell script that identifies all of the files recursively under a directory that are more than 10MB

Tags: shell, unix

Need to have a Shell script that will 
  * Identify all the files [ only files no dir ] under a directory recursively [ includes all sub directories] and list out those files which takes more than 10 MB of space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
find . -type f -size +10000000 -print|xargs ls -ld|more
```

will be a good alternative

but still what if we do not have the permissions inside the dir to do an `ls`/`find`

Comment: If you don't have permissions (and can't get them with e.g. sudo), there's nothing you can do.  You don't need `-type f` because a directory entry will never be that big.

Comment: also, you may override stderr if "permission denied" messages bother you by appending `2>/dev/null`

Answer (score 3):

```
find . -size +10M
```

The `+` means greater than.

EDIT: I added the directory argument.  It's optional for GNU find,

Comment: @Balualways, it works fine for me.  find 4.4.2 and bash 4.0.33.  What issue do you see?

Comment: You need to specify the path: `file . -size +10M`

Comment: perhaps copy/pasted without directory specified; then yes, it won't work "in bash".

Comment: @Balualways: That has nothing to do with Bash. Some versions of `find` require that you specify a directory - for some it's optional.

Answer (score 2):

```
find . -size 10M
```

Comment: That works if the files are exactly 10 megabytes. It won't find the ones that are more than 10MB.